# Let $A = \{m+2k\pi \mid m,k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Show that the closure of $A$ is the interval $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A = \{m+2k\pi \mid m,k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Show that the closure of $A$ is the interval $\mathbb{R}$.

Does anyone have ideas on this? I don't really know how to go about showing that the closure of $A$ is the interval $(- \infty , \infty)$. We know that $2\pi$ is irrational and then $k2\pi$ is still another irrational. We also know that closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing the set itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

It suffices to show $\{n\theta\}$ is dense in $(0,1)$, where $\theta$ is an irrational number, $\{a\}$ denotes the fraction part of $a$.

You can find a direct proof of the statement [here on page 1](http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math220/Math%20220A%20-%20HW%202.pdf). Or you can argue the sequence is equidistributed, hence dense in $(0,1)$

Answer (score 1):

The set $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$: We have $0\in A$, and if $a,b\in A$ then also $a+b\in A$ and $-a\in A$. Such subgroups are either $\{0\}$ or $a\mathbb Z$ for some $a>0$ or are dense.

To see this, let $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb R$.
Assume there eixts a smallest positive element $a$ of $G$.
Then $a\mathbb Z\subseteq G$. Let $g\in G$ be arbitrary and $k=\lfloor \frac ba\rfloor$. Then $na\le b<(n+1)a$, hence $0\le b-na<a$. From $b-na\in G$ and the minimality of $a$, we conclude that $b-na=0$. Hence $b=na\in n\mathbb Z$ and ultimately $G=a\mathbb Z$.
The remaining alternative is that there is no smallest positive element of $G$. This can be the case either because ther is no positve element in the first place - but then there cannot be negative elements either as their inverse would be positive; in this case we conclude $G=\{0\}$. Or there are positive elements, but for each positive element $a$ there exists a smaller positive element $a'$. As also $a-a'\in G$ and one of $a', a-a'$ must be $\in(0,\frac12a)$, we see that there exists a sequence of posirtive elements converging to $0$. Especially, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an element $a\in G$ with $0<a<\epsilon$.  We can show for any $x\in \mathbb R$ that $x\in \overline G$: Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $a\in G$ that is positive and $<\epsilon$. With $n=\lfloor \frac xa\rfloor$ we find  that $na\le x<(n+1)a<na+\epsilon<x+\epsilon$, i.e. $(n+1)a$ is an element of $G$ in the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$, as was to be shown.

Now your $A$ is certainly $\ne\{0\}$. If it were of the form $a\mathbb Z$, then for any two nonzero elements $an, nm$, their quotient $\frac{an}{am}=\frac nm$ would be rational. This is not the case for $A$, as $2\pi,1\in A$ and $\frac{2\pi}{1}$ is irrational. We conclude that $A$ is of the third kind, i.e. $\overline A=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Wow, you put a lot of effort into this answer. Thank you so much for giving a nice and clear answer.